# How do you install Emacs in ConEmu?

Tags: windows-10, emacs, conemu

Does ConEmu have an install manager? Is it possible to get one?

Comment: ConEmu is not a shell. http://conemu.github.io/#Disclaimer

Answer (score 0):

As Maximus noted, ConEmu is not a shell and so you do not install programs into it.

I'd recommend reading the link Maximus posted [in his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1244012/how-do-you-install-emacs-in-conemu#comment1824843_1244012) and learning more about what ConEmu is and isn't.